# How to use closure to fill array in php?

Tags: php

I want to avoid this notation:

```
$transactionsRows = [];

foreach ($data['invoces'] as $key => $invoice) {
   $transactionsRows[] = array();
}
```

Could I use closure in php to fill like this:

```
$transactionsRows = closure_fill(/* HERE FILL ARRAY AND RETURN */);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using this function: `array_values($array)`

[array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$transactionsRows = array_values($data)
```